# Save Multiple Variables to Class

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to programming and am trying to wrap my head around classes. I have created a class like the following:

```
    public class HistoricalEvents
    {
        public DateTime historicDate { get; set; }
        public string historicEvent { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to be able to go into a MySQL database, pull multiple events, and then display those events onto the screen. How do you create multiple HistoricalEvents from MySQL and then iterate through them to display them onto a screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need a class representing a single event, preferably named in the singular (eg `HistoricalEvent` instead of `HistoricalEvents`).

Then you can create a `List<HistoricalEvent>` like so:

```
public class HistoricalEvent 
{
    public DateTime historicDate { get; set; }
    public decimal historicEvent { get; set; }
}

List<HistoricalEvent> historicalEvents = new List<HistoricalEvent>();

historicalEvents.Add(new HistoricalEvent());
// ... etc etc ...
```

Once you have your list, you can iterate it like so:

```
foreach (HistoricalEvent historicalEvent in historicalEvents)
{
    // "historicalEvent" contains the current HistoricalEvent :)
}
```

Creating objects from a MySQL database is a lot more involved.  If you want to jump in, try [this tutorial](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314145) (provided by Microsoft), and perhaps look into [linq to objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx), but I would suggest becoming more familiar with C# first :)

### Edit:

That sounds a bit terse, so here's a similar example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

people.Add(new Person()
{
    Name = "Dave",
    Age = 43
});

people.Add(new Person()
{
    Name = "Wendy",
    Age = 39
});

foreach (Person person in People)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person.Name) // "Dave", then "Wendy"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses the [Connector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html) ADO.Net provider:

```
var list = new List<HistoricalEvent>();

using (var cn = new MySqlConnection())
{
    cn.Open();

    var sql = "SELECT Date, Event FROM HistoricalEvents";
    using(var cm = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn))
    using(var dr = cm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read)
            list.Add(new HistoricalEvent
            {
                historicDate = dr.GetDate(0), 
                historicEvent= dr.GetString(1)
             });

    }
}

foreach (var item in list)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}",item.historicDate,item.historicEvent);
```